# Reading partitioned parquet file into Spark results in fields in incorrect order

Tags: hive, apache-spark, parquet

For a table with

```
create table mytable (

  ..
) 
    partitioned by (my_part_column String)
```

We are executing a hive sql as follows:

```
   from pyspark.sql import HiveContext
   hc = HiveContext(sc)
   data = hc.sql("select * from my_table limit 10")
```

The values read back show the "my_part_columns" as the FIRST items for each row instead of the last ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is a known bug fixed in spark 1.3.0 and 1.2.1

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-5049